# PowerPoint automatically change to bold one of the numbering in a list that contains bold font

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, numbering

[image]
As you can see, the number 2 is in bold font, even though the number 1 is not. I assume this is because the second item starts with a bold-font word. But aesthetically, this is terrible. Is there a way to avoid this automatic bolding feature? I can not select the number unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get the "auto format" indicator under that builded numeral?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your speedy reply. Would you elaborate a bit? I don't know where to find the  auto-format option.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue, here is a similar thread "[Cannot unbold numbered list headers separately from the first text terms that follows it in Powerpoint 2019 (MS Office / PC)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-unbold-numbered-list-headers-separately/3c566648-5650-4aaa-8147-1a92517a2106)"

Comment: Yes, It is a known issue, and Microsoft is still working on a fix

Comment: How hard can this fix be? (It's still doing the same thing in mid-2023.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no direct way for doing what you're trying to do. You need a workaround:

1. Select M and use `Ctrl+B` to unbold it (This change is just temporary)
2. Place your cursor on the left of M and go to `Insert > Symbols`
3. Now here in the dialog box, Ensure that Font: `(normal text)` and form: `Unicode(Hex)` is selected.
4. Type in the character code as `034f` (also known as `Combining Graphene Joiner`) and click insert.
5. Make 'M' Bold again by pressing `Ctrl+B`.

Comment: Nice!  Alternatively, if your points are all one-liners and you're sure they won't line-break to a second line, you can just type a space ahead of each line and, optionally, adjust the offset from bullet to text using the ruler to move the text closer to the number. Marginally simpler, but falls apart with multi-line bullet points.